# regex reverse lazy quantifier

Tags: regex

say I have this string

```
X,,,X,,,X,,c,,X,,,X
```

and I want to catch the smallest string that matches `X.*c.*X`, which is X,,,X,,,**X,,c,,X**,,,X

the regex `X.*c.*X` will catch **X,,,X,,,X,,c,,X,,,X**

by making the second quantifier lazy `X.*c.*?X` I get **X,,,X,,,X,,c,,X**,,,X

but making the first quantifier lazy makes no difference `X.*?c.*?X` --> **X,,,X,,,X,,c,,X**,,,X

How can I tell the first quantifier to also be lazy, but from the other direction?

Answer (score 2):

#### explicitly disallow repetition of the starting substring.

In the example:

`X[^X]*c.*?X` --> XaaaXaaa**XaacX**aaaX

#### The multicharachter version:

(using negative look-around)

look for minimal `XY.*c.*XY` in string: `XY,,,XY,,,XY,,c,,XY,,,XY`

`XY((?!XY).)*c.*?XY` --> XY,,,XY,,,**XY,,c,,XY**,,,XY

Comment: This is correct. There is no "other direction" - regex always returns the earliest (leftmost) successful match. Thus, if both **XaaaXaaaXaacX**aaaX and XaaaXaaa**XaacX**aaaX match, you will always get the first one. The only way to return the second is to make sure the first one is unsuccessful.

Comment: A negated character class won't work for multicharacter values.

Comment: Yes, there is such a question on SO already. Yours is a dupe.